# Getting error while running `react-native run-android`

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-sdk-2.3

Whle running my react native code `react-native run-android` getting below error. It was working proper. But after taking fresh pull from git and `npm ci` and after I am running then getting this error.

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (30) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0-alpha01.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\gauraab\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9e02d64f5889006a671d0a7165c73e72\core-1.7.0-alpha01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

Comment: Since everyone is facing it just today, I think this could probably be because of our dependencies. Some update to minor version/patch version broke the android builds probably? In the dependencies, we can try providing an exact stable version number for our dependencies.

Comment: same problem after update Android Studio to 4.2.2

Comment: try to change the core library with stable version 1.6.0

Comment: @UsamaAltaf where is the core lib defined? I couldn't found ```androidx.core:core:1.7.0-alpha01``` in my project

Answer (score 30):

As some has mentioned, the problem is that the RN build automatically "upgraded" to androidx.core:core:1.7.0-alpha01, which depends on SDK version 30.

## The Fix

The fix is simply to specify android core version via androidXCore in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
        androidXCore = "1.5.0"
    }
```

## How I figured it out

Figuring this out was painful. I grepped for gradle files that would automatically upgrade packages like so

```
find . -name '*.gradle' -exec grep -H "\.+" {} \;
```

and found in `node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo/android/build.gradle` the following snippet

```
def androidXCore = getExtOrInitialValue('androidXCore', null)
  if (supportLibVersion && androidXVersion == null && androidXCore == null) {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
  } else {
    def defaultAndroidXVersion = "1.+"
    if (androidXCore == null) {
      androidXCore = androidXVersion == null ? defaultAndroidXVersion : androidXVersion
    }
    implementation "androidx.core:core:$androidXCore"
  }
}
```

Comment: 2021 React-native MVP

Comment: My release build's size has increased by 2x after this.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot. I also used `./gradlew :app:dependencies > dependencies.txt` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69031232/1395078) which helped me find the random dependency that was forcing `core 1.7`.

I had to hunt through several resolutions and eventually found it was Intercom bumping `activity-compose` between 10.6.2 and 10.6.3. I had `10+` so pinned it to 10.6.2. If it's a native package, finding the version to downgrade to is very easy with this repository explorer: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.intercom.android/intercom-sdk-base/10.6.2 - it shows dependencies.

Answer (score 22):

Apparently they just broke this today.

You can fix it by adding the following line to your app level build.gradle file (above the `android { }` block as a sibling):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
}
```

Finally, the Gradle build was successfully completed. Ref. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I got same issue. Just today. When I try to run locally, I got the exact same error. To get it run again, I update the field `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in file android > build.gradle from 29 to 30. Then, it can run again. If this answer fits with you, you can go with this way. But, personally, I'm lookin for solution without to change the value `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

Update: just change the `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: compileSdkVersion=29 to compileSdkVersion=30

Comment: 0.64.5 will have all sdk versions updated to 30, so you can use ReactNative upgrade tool and upgrade them all upfront to 30.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a screenshot of what I have done and it's run perfectly.
change **these lines from**

```
 compileSdkVersion = 29
 targetSdkVersion = 29
```

**to**

```
 compileSdkVersion = 30
 targetSdkVersion = 30
```

and also change this line from

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.+'
```

**to**
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'

[image]

Comment: I was able to build by only adjust 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0', leaving the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion at 29 - thus avoid upgrading the React Native NPM packages.

Answer (score 5):

First never use + to define the version of Libraries in Gradle, Try to give the latest version always.

If you are using Core KTX like below in your main Gradle dependencies

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
```

Just replace it to

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

Core and Core-ktx Version 1.7.0 released yesterday(September 1, 2021), which is causing the issues.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue is caused by `react-native-netinfo` 's old `version 4.0.0` which was configured to automatically pick up the latest published package of `androidx.core`... So in that case it did
I realized `androidx.core.core-1.7.0-alpha01` had been published right as the issue started occurring.

So to fix that I updated my `react-native-netinfo` package from `4.0.0` to `6.0.0` and this issue was resolved for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was just what I guessed. So, some updates to a minor version/patch version of an android dependency caused all this today.

To solve this, for the dependencies in your `build.gradle` file, if you have specified it to take the latest minor/patch version every time you build it, make it take an exact stable version.

For example, my appcompact dependecy was,

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.+
```

This means that it can update to 1.2.x or 1.3.x etc.. as and when such version updates get published. I changed this to depend on an exact stable version like below,

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0"
```

Hopefully, this solves the issue for everyone.

[image]

Comment: do you know which dependency it is? Caused I already specified with ```implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'```. But still got the same error

Comment: Probably the rc build could have caused this. And in general rc builds are quite buggy. Can you try a stable build?

Comment: did you use ```implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"```? Did you specified it, the version?

Comment: I don't use react-native. Mine is a native android project. So, you don't have to change it I believe since that did not break things for me.

Comment: I've try to change from ```androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01``` to ```androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0``` (like you did). But, still got the error

Comment: Can you get us the list of all dependencies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234408/discussion-between-chandrasekarg-and-akza).

Comment: See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68222185/70488

Answer (score 0):

Simple work around with complie version

- Change `compileSdkVersion=29` to `compileSdkVersion=30` and sync.

If you not willing to change the complie version,then

```js
 configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
        }
    }
```

add the above code in  `build.gradle` inside `android` and apply this

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha01'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on your top `build.gradle` at the bottom of `buildscript`. This will force anything to a specific version.

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.5.0"
            }
            
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core-ktx'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.5.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating version numbers to match those shown in the official template build.gradle file worked for me:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/template/android/build.gradle

```
 buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
 compileSdkVersion = 30
 targetSdkVersion = 30
 ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the single solutions above worked, but a combo of them worked for me, using RN `0.63.3` Here's the diff:

```
diff --git a/android/app/build.gradle b/android/app/build.gradle
index 9c014f8..1b59f65 100644
--- a/android/app/build.gradle
+++ b/android/app/build.gradle
@@ -139,6 +139,12 @@ def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
  */
 def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
 
+configurations.all {
+   resolutionStrategy {
+     force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
+   }
+}
+
 android {
     compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
 
diff --git a/android/build.gradle b/android/build.gradle
index a32892e..db64506 100644
--- a/android/build.gradle
+++ b/android/build.gradle
@@ -3,12 +3,13 @@
 buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.0'
     ext {
-        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
+        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
         minSdkVersion = 21
-        compileSdkVersion = 30
+        compileSdkVersion = 29
         targetSdkVersion = 29
         androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
         androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
+        androidXCore = "1.5.0"
     }
     repositories {
         google()
```

Answer (score -1):

Observing the same core library dependency is causing Gradle build issues for all.

Also, `clean project` or `Invalidate Caches/Restart...` options wouldn't help here.

> Affecting dependency: `'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha01'`

This dependency which was causing issue, for that I have made it stable in `build.gradle` file, then added a new line to solve dependency conflicts:

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
     force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the compileSdkVersion=29 to compileSdkVersion=30

Comment: @ChandrasekarG To most of us, this issue type is being observed in most recent, to be precise since yesterday. TBH, I haven't tried upgrading `compileSdkVersion`, will try and check.