# Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata FAILED react-native

Tags: gradle, react-native

I am making a release build for my project using `./gradlew assembleRelease` command but it gives me this error.

```
> Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0-alpha02.
     AAR metadata file: /Users/classic/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/64ba04558e5775ef86bc1e2e88b04a01/core-1.7.0-alpha02/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I cannot edit my `build.gradle` for fixing this error as project has some dependencies that break after changing `compileSdkVersion`.

**Edit**

I added the following line to my `android/app/build.gradle` but that didn't worked for me.

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

Related issue -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68207334/getting-error-while-running-react-native-run-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android app won't build -- The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/android-app-wont-build-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-an)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Zoe. I have fixed using the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I have fixed this error by adding the following line to `android/build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        androidXCore = "1.6.0" // <-- Add this line
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i was using old RN, so i upgraded then it worked for me. i did below changes. gradle clean, run the app

package.json

```
"react-native": "0.67.4", // previous 0.62.3
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.8.0", // previous "1.13.0",
```

android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties // previous 6.1.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

android\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2" // previous "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 30 // 29 previous
        targetSdkVersion = 30 // previous 29      
    }
...
}

   dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
___
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
    . . . 
    }
    }
```