# Android - App not running. Error : The minCompileSdk specified in a dependency's AAR metadata is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

A week ago the app was running perfectly but all of a sudden (without updating anything) the app is not running.

I am getting this error when I try to run the app

> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01.
> AAR metadata file: /home/kishan/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/af85edd7f0482dfc2b2e0c9a0519784e/work-runtime-2.7.0-beta01/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

Here is the screenshot for the same:

[image]

From my app level gradle file, I can see that I am having

`compileSdkVersion 30` and `targetSdkVersion 30`

Not sure what is causing this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App won't build in react native - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/app-wont-build-in-react-native-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok So finally I resolve this issue.

The issue was because of the dependency `androidx.work:work-runtime`
But I would like to first mention that I was not using that dependency in my project directly (not added in my app level gradle), probably some other dependency was using that internally.

So what I did is forcefully downgraded its version by adding this

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }
    }
```

inside

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
   //here
 }
}
```

and it resolved my issue.

Comment: Thank you for finding this solution. It did the trick for me, though my problem module was with 'androidx.browser:browser' which I also forced back to a stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Leave `targetSdkVersion 30`, but change `compileSdkVersion` to be 31.

The work manager beta probably also uses Android SDK 31.

When you compile Android SDK 30, work manager cannot compile since it uses Android SDK 31, and therefore uses new APIs which does not exist in Android SDK 30.

## Edit

Work Manager release notes of 2.7.0 [explicitly warns](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.7.0-alpha01) that this version and above only compatible with API 31.

So your options are:

- Use 2.6.0, which compiles API 30.
- Compile API 31 and try to handle the other broken dependencies - maybe Stack Overflow can help you out?

Comment: Is there any other solution? I can't do this because after doing this, few dependencies broke.

Comment: Android Developers explicitly warns that `work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha3` or above are only compatible with API 31. I’m updating my answer