# Android app won't build -- The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta03

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
```

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta03.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\8c2253a03dbeda2f20325192a9be3c20\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta03\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta03.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\878d97848eb81b0a418fd96bdef072ba\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta03\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

it suddenly started to show that and i dont know why, everything was okay, and now, it shows that error in every single project , i have seen some solutions about changing the targetsdk and compilesdk to 30, but i already have that and it doesnt work[app/buildgradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv6Uf.png)

Comment: downgrade your "androidx.window:window-java " dependency and then restart IDE by clearing and invalidating the cache.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve error: app:checkDebugAarMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014250/how-to-solve-error-appcheckdebugaarmetadata)