# Getting error while building Android app with React Native: The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I am trying to build react native project

but I got an error when running `npm run android`

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
```

Already gone through all the solution mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/android-app-wont-build-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-an), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511000/how-to-solve-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-aar-metadata), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054222/android-app-not-running-error-the-mincompilesdk-specified-in-a-dependencys), and [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33501) but could not solve it.

**android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Let me know if anyone require any additional information.

Comment: It clearly says that you should update the compileSdkVersion to 31 in order to work with this dependency. If it still doesn't work, try to update the targetSdkVersion along with the compileSdkVersion. Clearing the project caches etc. might be helpful too.

Comment: When I changed version to 31 then started getting this error:
```Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details```

Comment: Can you also paste the details about this error from the log?

Comment: @Mieczkoni here is the log after changing version to 31 
https://codeshare.io/Ad3odx

Comment: Can you also show us the app/build.gradle file? At least the dependencies list

Comment: @Mieczkoni just updated the question

Comment: I think you should find the dependency that is responsible for kotlin-reflect-1.4.21.jar from your error and update it so it fit the other Kotlin versions. More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159614/10508565

Comment: do you think is there anyway we can fix this without updating ```compileSdkVersion```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the `compileSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` to 31 and added `kotlinVersion = "1.7.20"` in **android/build.gradle**

```
kotlinVersion = "1.7.20"
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
```

You may have to specify `REACT_NATIVE_VERSION` so add these changes in **android/build.gradle**

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
```

Add the `android:exported="true"` in **Androidmanifest.xml** in `.MainActivity` tag like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:exported="true">
```

Anyone who still faces any issues comment on this answer, I will try my best to help you.