# How to solve: The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-3\46d15f5c58a469270eeba15db4463d05\transformed\appcompat-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-3\70088de83757cd2e92dadb8b386e6adb\transformed\jetified-appcompat-resources-1.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-3\6cbed90352b213553df3539e2e7f22af\transformed\jetified-emoji2-views-helper-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.0.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-3\09b79be83fba3907471fe1de63f439d3\transformed\jetified-emoji2-1.0.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-3\9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f\transformed\core-1.7.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-3\0e4a425e61d135d109d64d5f17d999df\transformed\jetified-lifecycle-process-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\caches\transforms-3\bca1bb61c15ab5807e64593ca04debef\transformed\lifecycle-runtime-2.4.0\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Comment: [There is a correct answer to this problem on this page ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034879/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys)

Comment: The solution is explained here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74361346/7370837)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74361346/7370837

Comment: The solution is explained in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74361346/7370837) https://stackoverflow.com/a/74361346/7370837

Answer (score 28):

> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30). Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0

The solution is in the error itself. There can be two solutions:

1. Use Android SDK version 31 in your project. Find `compileSdkVersion 30` in your app\build.gradle file, and change it to `compileSdkVersion 31`.
2. Force gradle to use an older version of the dependency `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0`. If you are not *directly* using this dependency, force gradle to use an older version like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
       configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy { 
            force 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle process:2.3.1'
            force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
            force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.3.1'  
            // force 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.0.0', This won't work, because it is made to work with Android SDK version 31 only
            force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'        
            force 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Force older versions of other dependencies causing errors like this only.

Follow only one out of these two steps

Comment: What gradle file is that example? app\build.gradle?

Comment: Yes, it's the module build.gradle

Comment: thanks for the solution. I had to use second solution because my code was dependent on old sdk android and i cannot change the sdk version as it breaks the code.

Answer (score 3):

In the  app/build.gradle file change the `compileSdk` to have a value of `31`

(Some of the newer components require an sdk version that is high than Android studio sets by default)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the error message
near what went wrong find "AAR metadata file: "
copy the location and paste it on file explorer

manually change the minCompileSdk=31 to 30
save

Answer (score 2):

you just need to install latest

1. **Android SDK version 32**.
2. change **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to **32**.
3. **sync now**.

Answer (score 1):

Need to upgrade android **SDK Version**
In **Android Studio** -> **Tools** -> **SDK Manager**
Download and apply **Android API 33 or 32**

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure copy of the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411447/ionic-cordova-build-always-use-last-version-of-androidx-appcompatappcompatn-and) but it should make the trick

"This issue is related to androidx.appcompat:appcompat 1.4.0-beta01 released on September 29, 2021.

As plugin.xml defines ANDROIDX_VERSION as major version 1 (1.+), 1.4.0-beta01 was used instead of 1.3.0. Unfortunately you cannot simply use cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic --variable ANDROIDX_VERSION=1.3.+ to overwrite the value, as the same version would be used for androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4 which exists as version 1.0.0 only.

I successfully used cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic --variable ANDROIDX_VERSION="[1.0, 1.4[" to get my builds fixed." - [Vivek Kachhwaha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9062273/vivek-kachhwaha)

Answer (score 0):

In React Native

In my case what worked for me was to change **compileSdk** version to **31**

this error face when I'm using google **Admob** in react-native

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
}
```