# Cordova App, minSdkVersion 30 and error "minCompileSdk (31) specified in a"

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

Tried all solutions [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/android-app-wont-build-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-an#new-answer) and it still doesn't work.
Can you help me? There is no case. I am using cordova 10.1.0

```
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
      dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF / com / android / build / gradle / aar-metadata.properties)
      is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
      Dependency: androidx.browser: browser: 1.4.0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`androidx.browser: browser: 1.4.0.`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/browser/browser/1.4.0) version which has been compiled using `targetSdkVersion 31`. In order to  use this, you need to make your app also compatible with version 31.
Go to `build.gradle` and update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // updated to 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myproject.name.testApp"
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 31  // updated to 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want update to version 31, you can downgrade your `androidx.browser` to [`androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/browser/browser/1.3.0) , this runs on sdkVersion 30

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any way to downgrade androidx.browser? It is not a dependency that I am using directly (it comes from when compiling cordova)

Comment: Did you update the Cordova version? Or some other library version update. Some update library must be using the lastest version of androidx.browser try finding it and downgrade it's version.

Comment: I finally could!

I had to not only set the browser version 1.3, but also the work-version to 2.6.0

I added in the build.gradle (inside app) this:
`def androidx_version = "1.3.0"
     implementation ("androidx.browser: browser: $ androidx_version") {
         force = true
     }

     def work_version = "2.6.0"
     implementation ("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version") {
         force = true
     }`
Thanks again!! You saved me