# Faild to run flutter app in Android Emulator with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, android-workmanager

When I run flutter app in Android Emulator with Android Studio,it throws a error like this:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: /Users/yh/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f/jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: /Users/yh/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f/jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11m 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

anyone can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android app won't build -- The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/android-app-wont-build-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-an)

Comment: make sure the compileSdkVersion and  minCompileSdk have the same values in you build.gradle file...