# React Native The minCompileSdk (31)) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i faced this problem while wants to run project with react-native run-android

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0.
AAR metadata file: /Users/neda/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/04e923929d67de3c3732020d273dc826/transformed/jetified-activity-compose-1.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

Thanks for help

Comment: Already answered in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/android-app-wont-build-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-an](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/android-app-wont-build-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-an)

Answer (score 1):

Update the compileSdkVersion to 31 in android/build.gradle (not android/app/build.gradle)

Comment: not working as for me. the error remains the same.