# Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm trying to build expo app for android using eas cli by running the command: eas build --platform android. It fails at 'Ran gradlew' command in the eas dashboard with the following error log

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
[stderr] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
[stderr]    > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
[stderr]      dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
[stderr]      is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
[stderr]      Dependency: androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0.
[stderr]      AAR metadata file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cfea03dc6ed1fbdd623bca4e7a73327b/transformed/browser-1.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 2m 57s
```

and here is my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
```

Comment: Plz include the name of the `module` mentioned by the error

Comment: Try to navigate to `android/build.gradle` and change `compileSdkVersion` to `30`

Comment: it is already 30

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034646/task-appcheckreleaseaarmetadata-failed-react-native

Comment: I have already checked that answer, it didn't work :(

Comment: Do you have `react-native-screens` installed ?

Comment: No I don't have it

Comment: Try to install relevant patch of your current react-native version here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: I changed the compileSdkVersion to 31 and it worked!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
file: /home/expo/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cfea03dc6ed1fbdd623bca4e7a73327b/transformed/browser-1.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

first open this file and see like this

```
aarFormatVersion=1.0
aarMetadataVersion=1.0
minCompileSdk=21   <------------this is you add in your file[aar-metadata.properties.]
minCompileSdkExtension=0
minAndroidGradlePluginVersion=1.0.0
```

Hope this will help you